# Why is my bind-time variable failing after migrating from WiX v3 to v4?

Tags: wix, wix4

Given following bundle:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
     xmlns:bal="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal"
     xmlns:fire="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/firewall"
     xmlns:util="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/util">
  <Bundle Name="!(bind.packageName.Setup)"
          Version="!(bind.packageVersion.Setup)"
          Manufacturer="!(bind.packageManufacturer.Setup)"
          UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseUrl=""
                                              SuppressOptionsUI="no"
                                              ShowVersion="yes"
                                              SuppressRepair="yes" />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage Id="Setup"
                  Compressed="yes"
                  Name="$(var.ProductName)"
                  SourceFile="foo.exe"
                  DisplayInternalUI="yes"
                  Vital="yes" />
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

With v3 I had no issues building the boostrapper, with the recent v4 release (4.0.2926.0) I am getting following error:

> 4>Bootstrapper\Bundle.wxs(14,0): error LGHT0298: Unresolved bind-time variable !(bind.packageVersion.Setup).
>   4>light.exe(0,0): error LGHT0001: Input string was not in a correct format.
>   4>Done building project "Bootstrapper.wixproj" -- FAILED.

Comment: Where did you get to download v4.0.2926.0. The version of the release available for download that i see is v4.0.2719.0.   http://wixtoolset.org/releases/v4-0-2719-0/

Comment: @KiranHegde http://wixtoolset.org/releases/, http://wixtoolset.org/releases/v4-0-2926-0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a bug in WiX v4. WiX v4.0 is still in active development and is pre-beta. Please file a bug at http://wixtoolset.org/issues/ so we don't lose it.